# Python Tix Help documentation view

Tags: python, tkinter, tix

Doing an application in Tix (Python), I want to include help documentation. I see a "regular" Help format i.e. the left-hand side is the index, a tree with the hierarchy of topics, and the right-hand side displays the currently selected topic. Additionally there should be a search capability as well. I was hoping that there was already a common dialog/framework for this but cannot find anything through google searches. It's not a big deal coding my own but would rather not recreate the wheel if not necessary.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the windows-style [chm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help) help?  Your description reminds me this.  ([Example image](http://www.writersua.com/articles/tools0801/images/6_wmplayer_chm.png))

Comment: yes something like that or PyCharm. I was considering writing small text files for each option and displaying them in a Text entry when the user selects that option from the left

Comment: I'd recommend using a [help authoring tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help_authoring_tool) like [Help N Doc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HelpNDoc) or similar.